# Vagrant machine - how to find out mysql username/password

Tags: mysql, vagrant, credentials

So, on atlas.hashicorp.com there are a lot of pre-installed machines, with PHP & MySql. But problem is, I can't find anywhere MySql credentials. I.e.:

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/webinfopro/boxes/ubuntu-xenial-lamp

I can access PhpMyAdmin, but I can't login. Tried all "usual" combination of username/password (root, vagrant, 12345678). But none of them works.
What's the point of installing MySql, when you don't give root user credentials?!?

I also followed some instructions to reset root user password:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

But I'm getting bunch of errors and process eventually fails. I'm not interested in debugging and solving numerous issues - just want to quickly have usable PHP 7 LAMP environment.

Comment: If the creators of those images don't supply passwords, I guess you'd be using the *upstream default* password you get when you would install MySQL.
If you haven't set any password during installation, MySQL will default to 'root' and no password. Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried. After init-in machine there is only vagrant file available, and mysql credential aren't in it. :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

tldr;

**Passwords are *123***

how to get there :

After I spin a VM from this box, I logged in and check few files from the mysql conf, and specially the file `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

```
[12:41 ]-[vagrant@symfony]-[/etc/mysql]
$ sudo more debian.cnf
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = 7WpHbEJmn1MxcfD9
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = 7WpHbEJmn1MxcfD9
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

so I could connect using the user from this file

```
[12:41 ]-[vagrant@symfony]-[/etc/mysql]
$ mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 17
....
```

I checked the user in table already created

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User             | Host        | Password                                  |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost   | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| root             | symfony.dev | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| root             | 127.0.0.1   | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| root             | ::1         | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost   | *8275381EF253977AC1CD84B53CAFE742E4288272 |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost   | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

so they all contained the same password .. ring the bell, checking

```
mysql> select password ('123');
+-------------------------------------------+
| password ('123')                          |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: I enter this file /etc/mysql/debian.cnf get username password and use PHPMyAdmin 
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = 7WpHbEJmn1MxcfD9  and login phpmyadmin changed user password. thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Just tried all passwords mentioned above (root, empty string, 123, etc.), nothing helped. I am using this box https://app.vagrantup.com/brownell/boxes/xenial64lemp.

After half an hour of bruteforcing, found that the password for `root` user is `secret`

Answer (score 3):

I believe the default is root:root for most of them.

$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
...

Comment: Not for this one. Frederic hacked it out.

Answer (score 3):

The answer for me to log in to MySQL on vagrant was with a username of root and when prompted for the pasword I just pressed enter. I.e...

**Username** : root

**Password**: (none, just press enter)